# Tail recursion vs Primitive Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am studying about haskell recursion. and when i read about recursion topic which talk about this two different type of recursion. i am understand how tail recursion works and its step to be done. i am not understand how is primitive recursion done in background. can anyone here help explain more about primitive and given some example ? 
For example : tail recursion

```
 sum:: [Int] -> Int
 sum [] = 0  
 sum (x:xs) = x+ (sum xs)
```

process  of sum [1,2,3,4]:

```
  = 1 + sum[2,3,4]
  = 1 + (2 + sum [3,4] )
  = 1 + ( 2 + ( 3 + sum[4]) )
  = 1 + (2 +  (3 ( 4 + sum[])))
  = 1 + (2 + ( 3 + ( 4 + 0 ) ) )  
  = 10
```

How does primitive recursion works?

Comment: They are not different types, tail recursive functions are a subset of all recursive functions. They can be transformed to a loop by a compiler and therefore not consume stack.

Comment: @fjarri it's not that clear-cut because of laziness.

Comment: That `sum` is not tail-recursive; that would be `sum = go 0 where go acc [] = acc; go acc (x:xs) = go (x + acc) xs`

Comment: I don't recommend using the concept of "tail recursion" to reason about  Haskell.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Why is that? GHC (potentially) performs tail call elimination as an optimization, so if you want to reason about the operational semantics of a Haskell program compiled with GHC you (potentially) need to know about tail call elimination.

Comment: @user2407038 Because sometimes it can harm performance to move to tail recursion. E.g. `map2 f xs = go xs [] where go [] acc = reverse acc ; go (y:ys) acc = go ys (f y:acc)` is tail recursive and far worse than the non-tail recursive `map f [] = [] ; map f (x:xs) = f x:xs`. It is unnecessarily more strict, it will prevent any list fusion / deforestation optimization to trigger, and it can allocate a long list even if only the first few elements are needed (e.g. `takeWhile p $ map2 f xs`). TL;DR: laziness and tail recursion is a strange mix.

Comment: @user2407038 "GHC (potentially) performs tail call elimination as an optimization." No. It does not, unless you are referring simply to the facts that all "calls" are "tail calls" and that GHC reduces expressions during evaluation. There is no code in GHC that selectively optimizes tail recursion in Haskel expressions, which is the context that TCO always comes up in. What it *does* do is left-most outermost reduction, which sometimes amounts to the same thing, so why talk about TCO when we should be talking simply about lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, we have tail recursion when we have a recursive function such that, when a recursive call is performed, the result of that call is the result of the function. In a sense, after the recursive call "there is nothing more to be done".

```
-- tail recursion
f1 n = if ... then ... else f1 (n - 1)
-- not tail recursion
f2 n = if ... then ... else 5 * f2 (n - 1)
```

Primitive recursion is another beast. We have primitive recursion when every recursive call is done using an argument which is a "direct subterm" of the original one.

```
-- primitive recursion (& non-tail recursion)
f1 (x:xs) = g x (f1 xs)   -- xs is  asubterm of x:xs

-- a tree type
data T = K Int T T
-- primitive recursion (& non-tail recursion)
f2 (K n l r) = h n (f2 l) (f2 r)                    -- l, r are subterms
-- non-primitive recursion (& tail recursion)
f3 (K n l (K m rl rr)) = f3 (K m (K n rl l) rl)     -- not a subterm
```